# C# Setting XmlSerializer options correctly?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

My XmlSerializer code is outputting Xml that is much more verbose than I require, how can I control the output settings properly?  This is the code:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());            
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
string xml = encoding != null ? encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray()) 
                              : Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```

And the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfProduct xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Product>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <ProductCode>A</ProductCode>
    <ProductDescription>Product A</ProductDescription>
    <Obsolete xsi:nil="true"></Obsolete>
  </Product>
</ArrayOfProduct>
```

I want to be able to format the Xml like so:

- Remove the xsi:nil="true" from lines with no value
- Collapse empty tags like `<Obsolete></Obsolete>` into the simple form `<Obsolete />`

Comment: It would be helpful if you copy the class structure with the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you decorate the class and members using [Serializable] the objects are serialized using the old methods which does not contains xsi:nil="true
But when you decorate the class with [DataContract] attribute the XmlSerializer will include the xsi:nil="true.

One way to remove xsi:nil="true is to 
decorate the class with [Serializable] attribute.

Comment: The class is only decorated with [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Product")]

Comment: Is this true in .NET 4? I've got EF POCO classes decorated with just `[Serializable]` that include these attributes...